Display a table inline with <p> text
I am trying to display a table inline within a p element. The result should look similar to this:
             *-----------------*
Text before. | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Text after.
             *-----------------*

As shown, the table needs to be centered vertically with the text. The table might have multiple rows.
The following works (I am using inline css in this example to simplify the post):
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        Text before.
        <table style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        Text after.
    </p>
</body>
</html>

HOWEVER, if I add <!DOCTYPE html> to the top of the file, the table appears below the "Text before."
There must be a difference between quirks mode (when the doc type isn't specified) and when the doc type is specified, but I don't know how to resolve it.
Thanks!

Block element inside a p is not valid. Also use flex for this issue.

Simply, in standard mode, the browser is closing the p element for you when it encounters the table in the code. The p is 100% wide so forcing the table to the next line.

The real question is "why a table"? An inline-flex or inline-grid span container would work better.

Is the data in the table really tabular? If so you may want to keep it as a table and sacrifice having a p element instead.

Paulie_D provided a solid solution. FWIW and not mentioned in my original post, I don't have control over the requirement that the table/grid is inside a p element. The surrounding html is coming from a database that has already created the p. The html page is soft-coded so users can insert tables at various points. Paulie_D's solution mostly solves it (except since I can't change the p's css, I can't vertically align the p and grid). I'll see if I can convince the powers-that-be to allow me to change the p class.

You can achieve the same, but need a bit of more css with it. And I think we need to replace the <p> with a <div> tag.


.inline-container {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Keeps the container inline */
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* Aligns vertically to the middle */
}

table {
  display: inline-table;
  /* Makes the table display inline */
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* Aligns the table in the middle of the line */
  margin: 0 5px;
  /* Optional: Adds spacing around the table */
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="inline-container">
    Text before
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    Text after
  </div>
</body>

</html>




Frankly, a table is not indicated here. An inline-grid container would be ideal.
Rows aren't necessary here but I've included them for clarity but it does require subgrid for optimisation.


p {
  outline: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: .25em;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  background: lightblue;
}

span .row {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
}
<p>
  Text before.
  <span class="grid">
    <span class="row">
      <span class="cell">Cell 1</span>
  <span class="cell">Cell 2</span>
  </span>
  <span class="row">
      <span class="cell">Cell 1</span>
  <span class="cell">Cell 2</span>
  </span>
  <span class="row">
      <span class="cell">Cell 1</span>
  <span class="cell">Cell 2</span>
  </span>
  <span class="row">
      <span class="cell">Cell 1</span>
  <span class="cell">Cell 2</span>
  </span>
  <span class="row">
      <span class="cell">Cell 1</span>
  <span class="cell">Cell 2</span>
  </span>
  </span>
  Text after.
</p>



BUT, as I said, rows aren't really required...


p {
  outline: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: .25em;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  background: lightblue;
}
<p>
  Text before.
  <span class="grid">
  <span class="cell">Cell 1</span>
  <span class="cell">Cell 2</span>
  <span class="cell">Cell 1</span>
  <span class="cell">Cell 2</span>
  <span class="cell">Cell 1</span>
  <span class="cell">Cell 2</span>
  <span class="cell">Cell 1</span>
  <span class="cell">Cell 2</span>
  <span class="cell">Cell 1</span>
  <span class="cell">Cell 2</span>
  </span>
  Text after.
</p>



